# Recursive PHP Programming: recall a function when it ends

Tags: php, function, recursion

I'm trying to develop a site which makes multiple calculations in one loop, and it takes from 20 secs up to 50-60 secs, based on server capacity.

The current solution is, that I call this function in every 60 secs with ajax, but this is a waste in the code: if the calculation ends in 30 secs, there is 30 secs more "waiting time".

I would like to optimize this code and simply recall this function once it ends. No return value is required.

I've tried the following solution, but somehow it's not working: after the first run the program quits, not calling the function again

```
<?php

  function Calculation() {

    // code that reads the input from a file
    // do the calculation stuff here that takes 20-60 secs

    Calculation(); // this should recall the function
  }

  Calculation(); // call for the first time

?>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO ! What do you mean by "somehow it's not working" ?

Comment: Well it runs one time, than quits, not recalling the function

Comment: and what's not working, you haven't shown is any actual code

Comment: Can you post your actual `Calculation()` function please?...

Comment: It should work ! You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AJAX, can wait for a response from the server  and then do something with that, it doesn't have to wait X seconds.

Comment: PHP has a maximum function call limit of 250 by default I believe. You need a guard that eventually stops recursion or you need to significantly increase that limit.

Comment: Hi exactly as said before, in any recursion function, you need to stop it in some time, you usually put an `if` to stop the cpu bleeding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the inputs guys, I already found a solution:

So now I set the ajax refresh time to 30 sec

```
<?php

  function Calculation() {

    $starttime = time();

    // code that reads the input from a file
    // do the calculation stuff here that takes 20-60 secs

    $endtime = time();

    if (($endtime - $starttime) > 30) { Calculation(); } 

    /* so basicly if the script runs more than 30 secs, 
    it won't wait the next refresh, just recalling itself. 
    If the script runs, the ajax won't reload the page as 
    mentioned. Once the program runtime will under 30 secs, 
    the basic ajax reload comes back. */

  }

  Calculation(); // call for the first time

?>
```

Comment: It seems you want an infinite `while(true) {Calculation();}` loop